# Audio player that supports ZIP archives

Tags: archive, audio-player

Is there anything better than `rhythmbox`, which does not support navigation between tracks inside archives?

Comment: Sorry, but why would you want to have audio files in zip archives? That doesn't make them any smaller, you'll have essentially 0 compression of an mp3 for example.

Comment: 1. It's primarily for organization; I want to be able to play all related tracks together. 2. MIDI files do compress.

Comment: 1. Is solved by every modern player that automatically scans your collection to build a library. 2. Use a filesystem that supports on the fly compression like `btrfs`. Of course you are free to choose. Just saying that there are more efficient solutions.

Comment: 1. No, it is not; the files don't have metadata. 2. I'm certainly not going to change my file system just for this; I have other considerations, constraints.
****
The is something Winamp easily did back in the 90s, so I'm not asking for much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DeaDBeeF (http://deadbeef.sourceforge.net/) via this [plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/deadbeef/files/plugins/ddb_archive_reader-x86_64-1.0-16.zip/download) can play music tracks from RAR, 7z and Gzip archives.

Visit this [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vmuc-wEs04w) for a short video showing this feature.

DeaDBeeF can be installed from this [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~starws-box/+archive/deadbeef-player)